# OData rest API with MS Project Online (SharePoint) "User not found in active directory or Project db

Tags: postman, odata, ms-project

I am trying to interact with MS Project Online (SharePoint) via OData rest Calls.
Obtaining the token via Azue ENTRA ID is done via an SSL certificate. The app registration seems to have the necessary permissions.
The app registration is registered in MS Project Online.
During calls I get the following error:

<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, System.InvalidOperationException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">User:<customercontent></customercontent> not found in Active directory or in project db.</m:message>
</m:error>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31pIp.png)

Thanls in advance for your help

Get the lis tof the Project